# problem adding additional column under multicolumn option in table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

**First part of the question:**
I have a table

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*9{c|}}\hline
A & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E} \\\cline{2-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} \\\cline{2-9}
 & U & V &  U & V & U & V & U & V \\\hline
y  & 7.23 & 6.39  & 7.76 &  6.93 & 2.81 &  2.54 & 0.59 &  0.55  \\ \hline
z  & 2.5503 &  2.2658  & 2.5345 &  2.3741 & 1.85 &  1.64 & 0.46 &  0.37   \\ \hline
$\sum{E^{i}_{U/V}}$  & & & & &  & & $\sim 1$ & $\sim 1$   \\ [1ex]  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which nicely re-produce what I want.

But as I want to add 3rd column under B, it does not work and keep giving me error "illegal character in array.arg".

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*10{c|}}\hline
A & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E} \\\cline{2-10}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} \\\cline{2-10}
 & U & V & W &  U & V & U & V & U & V \\\hline
y  & 7.23 & 6.39 & X & 7.76 &  6.93 & 2.81 &  2.54 & 0.59 &  0.55  \\ \hline
z  & 2.5503 &  2.2658 & X  & 2.5345 &  2.3741 & 1.85 &  1.64 & 0.46 &  0.37   \\ \hline
$\sum{E^{i}_{U/V}}$  & & & & & &  & & $\sim 1$ & $\sim 1$   \\ [1ex]  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

can anyone help me solve the issue please.

**Second part of the question:**

How can I remove the column lines from the last row for the columns with empty entries?

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `*10` is 1 copy of 0. You meant `*{10}` for 10 copies. The documented syntax _always_ has braces, although you can sometimes omit them in some cases eg single digits.

Comment: Please always make the examples complete starting from `\documentclass{article}` so people can easily reproduce the error.

Comment: wow, this is surprizing, *9 works but *10 doesn't !!! thanks! any insights for the second part of the question?

Comment: Why is that surprising? It is same as `\fbox ab` just boxes `a` you need `\fbox{ab}` to box more than one token.

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` will make an entry with no vertical rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here was that `*10` is interpreted as "one time". Commands in LaTeX always look for the next character. If you need to handle more then one character, you have to put it in braces. `*{10}`. You can see the same for `\textbf ab`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % remove this. It just shows that the second table is too large. 

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{|*9{c|}}\hline
        A & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E} \\\cline{2-9}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} \\\cline{2-9}
        & U & V &  U & V & U & V & U & V \\\hline
        y  & 7.23 & 6.39  & 7.76 &  6.93 & 2.81 &  2.54 & 0.59 &  0.55  \\ \hline
        z  & 2.5503 &  2.2658  & 2.5345 &  2.3741 & 1.85 &  1.64 & 0.46 &  0.37   \\ \hline
        $\sum{E^{i}_{U/V}}$  & & & & &  & & $\sim 1$ & $\sim 1$   \\ [1ex]  \hline
    \end{tabular}   

    \noindent % the table is still a bit to wide for this page...
    \begin{tabular}{|*{10}{c|}}\hline % important to set 10 into braces. (and every other multi digits number)
        A & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E} \\\cline{2-10} % 2-10, not 2-9, I guess...
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} \\\cline{2-10}
        & U & V &  W &  U & V & U & V & U & V \\\hline
        y  & 7.23 & 6.39 & X & 7.76 &  6.93 & 2.81 &  2.54 & 0.59 &  0.55  \\ \hline
        z  & 2.5503 &  2.2658 & X  & 2.5345 &  2.3741 & 1.85 &  1.64 & 0.46 &  0.37   \\ \hline
        $\sum{E^{i}_{U/V}}$  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & $\sim 1$ & $\sim 1$   \\ [1ex]  \hline
    \end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

It would not be helping with the horizontal width issue, but you could get rid of all those lines with use of the package `booktabs`. Here is a quick solution which might need some more tweaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize\noindent
\begin{tabular}{c*{2}S[table-format=1.4]c*{2}S[table-format=1.4]*{4}S[table-format=1.2]}\toprule
        A & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E} \\
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x} \\\addlinespace
        & U & V &  W &  U & V & U & V & U & V \\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}
        y  & 7.23 & 6.39 & X & 7.76 &  6.93 & 2.81 &  2.54 & 0.59 &  0.55  \\ 
        z  & 2.5503 &  2.2658 & X  & 2.5345 &  2.3741 & 1.85 &  1.64 & 0.46 &  0.37   \\\midrule 
        $\sum{E^{i}_{U/V}}$  & &  & &  & & & & {$\sim 1$} & {$\sim 1$}  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```